# add uploading features in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

how can i add this features in SharePoint 2010? plz help me
When file is uploaded to document library or an existing file edited and check-in then it should sync up with to folder on network drive. 
If new file is uploaded the same file should be immediately available on network drive and same for delete and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Event for Item Added, Item Updated and Item Deleted.

And all these events will be in Features. For creating feature, i would refer visual studio 2010, it will create all the files for features. You just need to create events.

Let me correct if you didn't want code.

Thanks

Comment: thanks....I am beginner in SharePoint and not so well in programming also. so if u suggest me how to create that event it will very helpful for me.

Comment: Please check below links http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-lists-and-event-handlers/

Comment: http://www.expertsupdates.com/sharepoint-articles/create-event-handler-for-sharepoint-list-31.aspx

Comment: Please let me know if you need further help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this  by mapping the document library to the map drive on local computer..

Please correct me if this is not your requirement

http://ashrafhossain.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/using-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/

Comment: but it will be a manual process i think. i want to know about automatically synchronization between SharePoint and network drive. Please give me some light on that. thank you

Comment: sorry I was unable to make out your point earlier. Actually I have already a network drive. Now is that possible mapping the document library in my existed network drive? thank you

Comment: Follow this link it may help you. http://www.windows-tech.info/6/562affa8a4105fca.php